# DataGridView Column Template

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView on my Form which is being populated with database records on the click event button.
How can I populate another two column template programatically at run time?

The two column template are **Qty In Stock** and **Status**
This is my datagridview what looks like when populated from database on click event button...

```
===============================================================
FoodName        FoodType     Qty In Stock     Status
===============================================================
Olives          Starter                     
Soup            Starter                     
Caprese     Starter
Bruschetta     Starter
Mushroom     Starter
Antipasto     Starter
Scallops     Starter
Calamari     Starter
Crab Avocado    Starter
Pizza Bread     Starter
===============================================================
```

And this is the datagridview what I want to look like populating the other two columns at the run-time

```
=================================================================
FoodName        FoodType     Qty In Stock     Status
=================================================================
Olives          Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Soup            Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Caprese     Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Bruschetta     Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Mushroom     Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Antipasto     Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Scallops     Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Calamari     Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Crab Avocado    Starter      0                Allways On Stock
Pizza Bread     Starter      0                Allways On Stock
=================================================================
```

Here is the code generating the datagridview from database on click event button...

```
private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ColFoodQtyStock = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ColFoodStatus = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        private void cmdStarters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
            connBuilder.DataSource = @"C:\Users\AP_AE\Desktop\DTPOS_APP\DataBase\DtposMenu.accdb";
            connBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            connBuilder.Add("Jet OLEDB:Engine Type", "5");

            // Food SQL Query
            string foodTypeSql = @"SELECT FoodName, FoodType FROM Food WHERE FoodType = @foodType";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 60;
                //====================================\\
                dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                dataGridView2.Visible = false;
                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand foodsCommand = new OleDbCommand(foodTypeSql, conn);
                    OleDbParameter foodType = foodsCommand.Parameters.Add("@foodType", OleDbType.VarChar, 15);
                    OleDbDataAdapter foodsDa = new OleDbDataAdapter(foodsCommand);
                    //DataRow dr;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    conn.Open();
                    foodType.Value = "Starter";
                    foodsDa.Fill(ds, "Food_table");

                    conn.Close();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    dataGridView1.DataMember = "Food_table";

                    dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(ColFoodQtyStock, ColFoodStatus);

                    DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
                    dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new Font("Verdana", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

                    this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 420;
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 180;
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 300;
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 308;

                    // ColStatus 
                    ColFoodStatus.HeaderText = "Status";
                    ColFoodStatus.Name = "ColFoodStatus";

                    // ColQtyStock
                    ColFoodQtyStock.HeaderText = "Quantity In Stock";
                    ColFoodQtyStock.Name = "ColFoodQtyStock";

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Could someone help me to modify the code on my click event button to solve this problem please

Thanks in advance

lapeci

Comment: Where does the data for those additional columns come from? If they are in another table in the database, then you need to update your sql query to join the two tables and bring in all 4 columns.

Comment: Hi Brian, The data for additional columns they dont come from nowhere, they must be generated at run time.

Comment: Hi Waleed, The data for additional columns they dont come from nowhere, they must be generated at run time.

Comment: I am not sure how you will be able to calculate "Qty in Stock". You will need to have some sort of persisted data pertaining to sales, which would be in the database. If it is in the database, then it would make sense to calculate it as part of your original query. Maybe I am just not understanding what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi Waleed, basically im not trying to calculate the "Qty In Stock", all I want is how to generate this two column template at run time (like the example I posted earlier), Waleed I,m new to C# programming, if you could please modify my code above how to generate the two columns, it would be greatfull honestly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want columns added at runtime (although Qty in Stock sounds like a database column) then the easiest way is to add them directly to your dataset.

```
    ...    
    foodsDa.Fill(ds, "Food_table");

    //add extra column structures to dataset
    ds.Tables["Food_table"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColFoodQtyStock", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
    ds.Tables["Food_table"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColFoodStatus", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    //loop through all the rows and add the data to the new columns dynamically
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Food_table"].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ds.Tables["Food_table"].Rows[i]["ColFoodQtyStock"] = 0;
        ds.Tables["Food_table"].Rows[i]["ColFoodStatus"] = "Always On Stock";
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "Food_table";

    DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
    dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new Font("Verdana", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 420;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 180;
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 300;
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 308;
}
catch (Exception ex)
...
```

PS: you don't need to call .Open() or Close() on a connection when using a dataAdapter as it is done automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much that did solved my problem I appreciated, once again thanks a lot